# cb is not a function - when handling the unhandled Promise Rejection using winston

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, winston

[image: This is a logfile image where am getting cb is not a function]

Getting the cb is not a function when I run this code to handle the uhandled Promise rejection using winston. In console it shwos exact error but it stores cb is not a function.

```
winston.add(winston.transports.File, {
  filename: "logfile.log"
});
winston.add(winston.transports.MongoDB, {
  db: "mongodb://localhost/vidly-practice",
  level: "info"
});
process.on("uncaughtException", ex => {
  console.log("WE GOT UNHANDLED EXCEPTION");
  winston.error(ex.message, ex);
});
process.on("unhandledRejection", ex => {
  winston.error(ex.message, ex);
  process.exit(1);
});
const p = Promise.reject(new Error("Unhandled rejection.........!!!"));
p.then(() => console.log("Done"));
```

> Listening on port 3000... error: Unhandled rejection.........!!!
>   Error: Unhandled rejection.........!!!
>       at Object. (F:\Node js Course[FreeCoursesOnline.Me] CodeWithMosh - The Complete Node.js Course\9- Mongoose- Modeling
>   Relationships between Connected Data\9.7- Project- Build the Rentals
>   API\after\vidly\index.js:36:26)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:10)
>       at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11

Comment: Missing code and too less info about what your plan is. Please add more info.

Comment: Kindly check what am missing in the code? i am storing error message and error in  logfile.log, it shows output with exact error but in log file it shows cb is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I don't use winston.

You're passing `ex` as your 2nd parameter which is expecting a function. In your given code the `ex` is not a function but an instance of `Error` or something similar.

You should do something like the snippet below.

```
// NOTE: this code is not tested
process.on("unhandledRejection", (ex) => {
     winston.error(ex.message, () => { // this should be your callback
         // do something inside your callback function
     });
     process.exit(1);
});
// NOTE: this code is not tested
```

Or if you know TypeScript, read the typings: https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/master/index.d.ts#L60

Or this one, which is suited for your case: https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/master/index.d.ts#L68